# What was Pope Innocent VIII's reaction to the Edict of Expulsion of the Jews in 1492?

Tags: jews, spain, catholic-church, renaissance, pope

What was the reaction of the Pope of the Catholic Church to the Edict of Expulsion of the Jews of Spain on March 31, 1492?

Did Pope Innocent VIII (d. July 25, 1492) condemn publicly Spain's decree? Was there any papal bull or any other document issued at the moment by the Catholic Church?

EDIT: I've only looked at the Wikipedia pages of the Alhambra Decree, Pope Innocent VIII and Pope Alexander VI. This last pages says that Pope Alexander VI which papacy began in 1492 welcomed in Rome Jews expelled from Spain. This last move made me wonder what was the reaction from the Popes at the moment and if they reacted publicly.

Comment: This [list](http://www.zionism-israel.com/hdoc/Papal_Bulls_Jews.htm) of papal bulls regarding Jews, lists nothing for Innocent VIII, so one can reasonably conclude that he did not issue any.

Comment: @MoisheKohan In fairness, that is only a "_partial list of Papal Bulls and other relevant documents_ ...".  Just because it doesn't list anything for Innocent VIII doesn't necessarily mean he didn't issue any.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Agree, this is why it was left as a comment and not an answer. I spent enough time on this to conclude that the only way to properly answer this question is for somebody who reads Latin to go through the complete list of bulls issued by Innocent VIII and check if any are related to Jews. Since I do not read Latin, I am unqualified for that task.

Comment: Dear @sempaiscuba: Thank you for dealing with this question.

Comment: Why does Innocent have to issue any bulls?  Ad Abolendam, was already issued at the end of the 12th century by Pope Lucius III